# How do I create a stored procedure that takes a list of products or a datatable as a param, then insert into a table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm fairly new to SQL Server any input and advice would help greatly.

I have 3 tables which are in one-to-many relationships.

Table `Person` holds customer info

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
[PID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
[CAddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Ccity] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Cstate] [varchar](2) NULL,
[Czipcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Ccountry] [varchar](255) NULL,
[Cphone] [varchar](25) NULL,
[Cemail] [varchar](255) NULL,
[CipAddress] [varchar](255) NULL)
```

Table `Transaction` holds their transaction

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction](
[TID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateOfTransaction] [date] NULL)
```

with a third table, `TransactionDetail`, which holds transaction details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionDetail](
    [TDID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ProductQTY] [int] NULL,
    [ProductPrice] [decimal](18, 2) NULL)
```

I would like to create a stored procedure to insert once into the `Person` table then insert multiple details into the third table.

this is what i got i'm not sure if this is correct?

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TransactionTableType AS TABLE
    ( TID int, ProductID int, ProductName varchar(255), ProductQTY int, ProductPrice decimal(18,2) )
    go
CREATE PROCEDURE insertTransacion
@NewProduct dbo.TransactionTableType READONLY,
@FirstName varchar(255),
@LastName varchar(255),
@CAddress varchar(255),
@Ccity varchar(255),
@Cstate varchar(2),
@Czipcode varchar(20),
@Ccountry varchar(255),
@CPhone varchar(25),
@Cemail varchar(255),
@CipAddress varchar(255),
@DateOfTrans date
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @Pid int
insert into Person(FirstName,LastName,CAddress,Ccity,Cstate,Czipcode,Ccountry,Cphone,Cemail,CipAddress) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@CAddress,@Ccity,@Cstate,@Czipcode,@Ccountry,@CPhone,@Cemail,@CipAddress)
SET @Pid = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
insert into PTransactions(PID, DateOfTransaction) values (@Pid, @DateOfTrans)
DECLARE @Tid int
SET @Tid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into TransactionDetail(TID, ProductID, ProductName, ProductQTY, ProductPrice) Select @Tid, ntd.ProductID, ntd.ProductName, ntd.ProductQTY, ntd.ProductPrice from @NewProduct as ntd
end
```

Not sure how to do this in a stored procedure I know how to do it programmatically in asp.net using ado, however I'm trying to avoid that. Sorry for the grammar.

Comment: Just a comment, normalize before going any further. The transaction table is pretty much a Person table with a TransactionId and IPAddress. Also, no need to store ProductName in TransactionDetail, this should be in a Product table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Is it valid to have a TransactionDetails record with a NULL TID?

Comment: i could make it not null normalizing the tables thank brian will normalize.

Comment: How do you plan to parse in the data to the stored proc? Is there a set number of products that you want to add, or is it dynamic? If it's dynamic then you probably need to join them all together in a comma seperated list (or some other delimiter) and then seperate them out in the stored proc. Probably easier to do it in asp.net. Is there any particular reason you need it in a stored proc?

Comment: easier to insert multiple tables in a stored procedure i was thinking of passing the person table and transaction as a single param, which leaves the transaction detail as a datatable or something like that since the transaction detail may have multiply records involved.

Comment: You can write two store procedure first insert in person table and check if insert successfully then call second store procedure in person store procedure. In second procedure you pass comma separated data which pass in second procedure which can handle by while loop and insert multiple products.

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? 2005? 2008? 2012?

Comment: @Neo Could you be more specific

Comment: it needs to rolled in a transaction otherwise 1 insert can fail other will succeed without a parent or related record

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't, although there are a couple of options open to you.

You can either create a SP to enter the person data, and a separate one to insert the data - one line at a time. Return the person id value with the first call and use that in the subsequent SP calls to insert the data. If you go down this path, make sure you wrap the calling code up in transaction objects so you can roll back the whole lot if you have a problem. You don't state what language you're using for the rest of your code?

Second option is to look at the SQL Bulk Insert command - this is best if you have **a lot** of data to add into the third table. But involves writing that data out to a file first - slight pain but it's then very fast. Very good if you have thousands or more rows to add.

Couple of other options out there as well depending on your development language.

Cheers
Simon